# Convergence Sequence on compact set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact and $x\in A$. Suppose that $x_n$,$n\in N$ is a sequence in $A$ with the property that every convergent subsequence of $x_n$ converges to $x$. Prove that the sequence $x_n$ converges.

I try to argue by contradiction. ie there exist a $1$ and for all $n$ we can make distance of $x_n$ and $x$ greater than $0$ equal to $1$. but how to go the further. please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean, if $x_n$ doesn't converge to $x$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $N$ there is $n > N$ with $\text{dist}(x_n, x) > \epsilon$.

Hint: the $x_n$ with $\text{dist}(x_n, x) > \epsilon$ form a subsequence.  Now use the fact that every sequence in a compact set has a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_{n_{i}}$ be the subsequence of all points of $x_{n}$ such that $|x_{n}-x| < \varepsilon$ and let $x_{n_{j}}$ be the subsequence of all $x_{n}$ such that $|x_{n}-x| \geq \varepsilon$. Since A is compact, there is a subsequence of $x_{n_{j}}$ that converges to x, i.e. there exists some points in $x_{n}$ such that $|x_{n} - x| < \varepsilon \wedge |x_{n} - x| \geq \varepsilon$. That's a no-no.

Comment: Thank you if A is not compact then it won't true. am I right? how do we create counter example.